# Running SSRS and SSAS from different server than the primary database instance(SQL Server Engine)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs, ssas

Right now both SSRS, SSAS  and SQL Server Engine are on the same server.  We are using 2008R2 Enterprise. We are thinking to upgrade to SQL Server 2012 or 2014. and We want put on separate serve the SQL Engine and SSRS,SSAS on SQL Server 2012 or 2014.

What we want is:

> Server 1 for SQL Server Engine
>
> Server 2 for SSRS and SSAS

My questions are:

1. How they talk each other(the two Servers)?
2. Where the cube for SSAS stored?
3. Where the report builder build report?
4. Can you give my high level explanation how server 1 and server 2 interact or direct me some document I can read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.How they talk each other(the two Servers)?

From the database engine perspective, both SSRS and SSAS are clients like any other application.  These query data from SQL Server using SQL queries.  Microsoft just chose to include these components with SQL Server licensing and media.

> 2.Where the cube for SSAS stored?

On the server with SSAS installed (server 2).

> 3.Where the report builder build report?

On the server with SSRS installed (server 2).

> 4.Can you give my high level explanation how server 1 and server 2 interact or direct me some document I can read?

In addition to what I mentioned in #1, client applications can query the SSAS server without involving the database engine at all after cubes are built.  However, SSRS has a dependency on the reporting server databases as well as data sources that may also be on SQL Server.

Below are a couple of architecture diagrams you might find useful:

SSAS:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510502.aspx

SSRS:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157231.aspx

Comment: Now all the data ,cubes and everything are on server 1 d: drive. when we separate the server. Is going to be the data on server 1 d: drive where as the cubes and report builder stay on server 2 lets say d:drive?

Comment: when we open one of the  cube is the data comes from where server 2 drive at  or there is a pointer to direct to where the data stored (server 1 d: drive) ? I am wondering whether the cube will be as a big as the original data size or not?

Comment: @SQL_DBA_Bini, the general rule of thumb is SSAS disk space needs are about 20% of the database size.  Your space needs may be higher if you have large fact tables or large dimensions.

Comment: I'm seeking a confirmation on my understanding that - A SQL Server instance is the highest level umbrella under which all features (DB engine, SSIS, SSAS, SSRS etc) exist.  So one can have either one or all four features on the same instance. Either of the features can't exist without a SQL Server instance. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @RBT, those features can be installed independently as you said. Note that SSIS is a shared component and not tied to a specific instance. This is a consideration when multiple instances (default and/or named instances) are installed on the same box.

Comment: ok. So at least SSAS, SSRS and database engine are **always** tied to the default or named SQL Server instance on the box they are being installed. The key thing I was searching was whether an SSAS can exist on a box without a SQL Server instance or not, to which the answer is - *No*.

Comment: So a SQL Server instance is a prerequisite for installing SSAS or it will create one during its installation if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @RBT, SQL Server setup will create a new instance if you don't already have a SQL instance installed. If you already have one or more instances, you can select which one to add the SSAS feature to. Although you could create a new instance for SSAS along side of other instances, that would typically be done in specialized scenarios like different SQL versions on the same box.